# Trigonometric linear in $\tan(180/7),\tan(360/7),\tan(540/7)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Without using a computer but using pen and paper only, can anyone please help me calculate, simplify / evaluate the following?

$$ 
  \frac{\tan(180^{\circ}/7)}{\tan(360^{\circ}/7)} - 
  \frac{\tan(360^{\circ}/7)}{\tan(540^{\circ}/7)} - 
  \frac{\tan(540^{\circ}/7)}{\tan(180^{\circ}/7)} 
$$

It evaluates to $-9$. This result is given for reference.

Comment: I assume you mean $180^\circ$ etc.?

Comment: @mrf: BTW, is your logo bi-polar coordinates map?

Comment: @Narasimham No, it's an excerpt of a plot of some rational function (color coding the argument).

Comment: @mrf sir do you have any solution without using computer?

Comment: It may have to do with like complex $ z^7 + 1 =0 $

Answer (score 1):

EDIT1:

Among all arguments the highest common factor is $ (\pi/7) $ and $ \tan ( m \pi/7) $ can be expanded in terms of  $ T_t =\tan (\pi/7), $ as m is an integer.

With obvious multiple argument notation:

$$  F(t) =  \dfrac{T_t}{T_{2 t}} -\dfrac{T_{2t}}{T_{3 t}} - \dfrac{T_{3t}}{T_{ t}}    $$

$$ T_t = t $$

$$ T_{2t}=  \dfrac{2t}{1 - 2 t^2}   $$

$$ T_{3t}=  \dfrac{3 t- t^3 }{1 - 3 t^2}   $$

and simplify it.

But it does simplify to the constant $ ( -9) $ you gave !

EDIT2:
Honest, I used computer just to cross-verify that hand work cannot simplify fractions.

EDIT3:

**$ F( \tan7 t) = 0 $**.  But using only paper/pencil such conclusion may not be so obvious to come to.

Comment: So is there any solution without computer help?

Comment: I suppose it is there, but cumbersome and tedious. The computer has necessity wise made many of us lazy.